# "The system cannot find the path specified. " stdout: "" command: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf

Tags: laravel

im using this package 
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy

to generate pdf files, i follow up the docs for installation but im getting this error

**Config/snappy.php**

```
<?php

return array(


    'pdf' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary'  => base_path('vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386/bin/wkhtmltopdf-i386'),
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(),
        'env'     => array(),
    ),
);
```

**PrintCntroller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PDF;
use App\Caisse;

class PrintController extends Controller
{
    public function testPdf()
    {
        $caisse = Caisse::where('type',1)->first();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('print.test',[
            'date' => date('M-Y'),
            'caisse' => $caisse,
            ]);
        return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
    }
}
```

**error image**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

a cashe problem :( i solved it with this

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```